# Can you also slurp soups that don't have any noodles in Japan?

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, culture, etiquette

I am writing a paper and couldn't find sources on just slurping the soups. Could anyone help.

Comment: You *can* do a lot of things. On the other hand, whether it is traditionally done and how locals would react if a tourist did so would be a much more reasonable question for a travel site.

Comment: Typically, Japanese soups are not eaten using spoons.

Comment: ?? This IS a travel site, and OP said nothing about spoons.

Answer (score 10):

**No**, that would be kind of weird.  For ramen, soba, etc, you don't really slurp the *soup*, you slurp the noodles after picking them up with chopsticks.  For noodleless soups like miso, there's nothing slurpable to pick up with chopsticks, and it makes no more sense to slurp it than it does to slurp a glass of water or a cup of tea.